Changing resolution based on input using Model Designer
I'm currently working with Model designer in QGIS.
Consider two Rasters R1 and R2. I want to reproject the coordinate system and change the resolution of Raster R1 to that of Raster R2. Is it possible to do so using Model Designer? I've noticed that changing the resolution is not possible using Warp(reproject) tool.


Raster Layer Properties to calculate the pixel size of Raster 2 (the reference layer)
Warp Raster 1 and set the Target CRS to that of Raster 2, and the Output file resolution to the Pixel size calculated with Raster Layer Properties:



